# AttributeError: module 'uwsgi' has no attribute 'masterpid'

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, uwsgi

I'm trying to run some unit tests on a Flask api built in python, but when importing the app in the setUp of the class, I'm getting this:

def setUp(self):

> ```
>   from app import OPERATIONS_CATALOG_SVC
> ```

test/common/operations/test_common_services.py:10:

---

app.py:12: in 
from uwsgi_tasks import TaskExecutor, task
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/**init**.py:2: in 
from uwsgi_tasks.tasks import (

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import inspect
import collections
import logging
import threading
import traceback
import calendar
from contextlib import contextmanager
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import os
import six
import warnings
from uwsgi_tasks.utils import (
    import_by_path,
    get_function_path,
    ProxyDict,
)


try:
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
    from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle


try:
    import uwsgi
```

> ```
>   if uwsgi.masterpid() == 0:
> ```

E       AttributeError: module 'uwsgi' has no attribute 'masterpid'

.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py:31: AttributeError

Pip list:

aniso8601                                    9.0.1
asgiref                                      3.7.2
attrs                                        23.2.0
cb-common                                    1.14.87
certifi                                      2024.2.2
cffi                                         1.16.0
charset-normalizer                           3.3.2
click                                        8.1.7
cloudant                                     2.13.0
contextvars                                  2.4
coverage                                     4.5.4
cryptography                                 41.0.4
deepdiff                                     5.8.1
Deprecated                                   1.2.14
dnspython                                    2.1.0
Flask                                        2.2.5
Flask-Executor                               0.9.3
flask-restplus                               0.12.1
flask-restx                                  1.0.5
idna                                         3.6
ijson                                        2.3
immutables                                   0.20
importlib-metadata                           6.11.0
iniconfig                                    2.0.0
itsdangerous                                 2.0.1
Jinja2                                       3.1.2
jmespath                                     0.10.0
jsonschema                                   4.17.3
MarkupSafe                                   2.1.2
mock                                         3.0.5
mongomock                                    3.17.0
opentelemetry-api                            1.20.0
opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-thrift         1.20.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation                0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-aiohttp-client 0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi           0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-elasticsearch  0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi        0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask          0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-pymongo        0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-requests       0.41b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-wsgi           0.41b0
opentelemetry-sdk                            1.20.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions           0.41b0
opentelemetry-util-http                      0.41b0
ordered-set                                  4.1.0
packaging                                    23.2
path.py                                      10.1
pika                                         1.2.0
pip                                          23.2.1
pluggy                                       1.4.0
pycparser                                    2.21
pycryptodome                                 3.10.1
PyJWT                                        2.4.0
pymongo                                      3.11.4
pyrsistent                                   0.20.0
pytest                                       7.2.0
pytest-cov                                   2.6.1
pytest-html                                  4.0.0
pytest-metadata                              2.0.0
pytest-mock                                  1.10.4
python-dotenv                                0.8.2
pytz                                         2024.1
PyYAML                                       6.0.1
redis                                        5.0.0
requests                                     2.31.0
requests-mock                                1.5.2
sentinels                                    1.0.0
setuptools                                   65.5.0
six                                          1.16.0
statsd                                       3.3.0
thrift                                       0.16.0
typing_extensions                            4.9.0
urllib3                                      2.2.0
uWSGI                                        2.0.22
uwsgi-tasks                                  0.7.3
Werkzeug                                     3.0.1
wrapt                                        1.16.0
zipp                                         3.17.0

python version: Python 3.11.5

Answer (score 0):

There may be name conflict somewhere. Make sure you do not name your file/folder with python package name.

Start from scratch and it should be fine.

`masterpid()` is available in `uwsgi` package.

Link to the document : https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API.html#uwsgi-masterpid

**uwsgi.masterpid()**

> return the current pid of the master process